# Dymo LabelManager PnP Postscript file paperSize

Tags: command-line, ghostscript, postscript

Here I am again with a PostScript question.

This time I'm trying to print this simple file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%Requirements: color
%%LanguageLevel: 2
% 72 PostScript points = 1 inch
% 1 inch = 2.54 cm
%%PageBoundingBox: 8 8 300 36
<< /PageSize [300 36] >> setpagedevice

<< /Orientation 3>> setpagedevice

/ArialBold findfont 10 scalefont setfont
30 18 moveto (Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet) show
showpage
```

As you can see it's only a single line, the label I want to print to is very small too, it's 12 mm wide and as long as you need (normally).

I'm getting the text to print correctly onto the label, but only up to the 2nd "amet". After that one the printer stops and says he is done, and he always prints exactly the same length (9cm) no mather what page size I set.

Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The command I use to print is:

```
C:\gs\gswin32c.exe -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -dNoCancel -dNOPAUSE -dSAFER -sOutputFile="%%printer%%DYMO LabelManager PnP" -q "C:\gs\dymo.ps" -c quit
```

Answer (score 1):

I would always start by using the display device. If you remove the -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 Ghostscript will open a window and show you what it thinks the result will be, if that is incorrect then the mswinpr2 isn't going to be better. Try that and see what happens, this will also show you if you are falling off the media as the GS window is only white where the media is set.

Comment: KenS: the GS windows shows me the entire document (granted if I play with the pageSize). But if I then readd the -sDEVICE it just prints the same width again...

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm puzzled, GS is obviously correctly handling the PostScript, you are using the same PageSize for your printer as when running under GS ? Perhaps its something to do with your printer, I'm afraid I don't have one of these to experiment with.

Comment: Yup same PageSize when running under GS, thanks for the help tho. Didn't know about dropping the -sDEVICE to see the document in GS.